# How to autofill an array in java..?

Tags: java, arrays

How can i autofill an array (specially multidimensional) in java with '-1' without using any loops..?

I know by default java initialize all the elements of array with '0'. But what if i want to replace all zeroes with -1 at once..! Without using any loop.

Is there any shortcut available..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) to fill a one dimensional array but you'll have to loop for multi-dimensional arrays.

```
    int[][] array = new int[100][100];
    for (int[]a : array) {
        Arrays.fill(a, -1);
    }
```

What's your reason to avoid loops ? If you're concerned with performances (and you're sure there is a problem) you might do what is often done, that is flatten your array in a one-dimensional one :

```
 int[] flatarray = new int[width*height];
```

then you can fill it with only one `fill` (which hides a loop, though) and many manipulations would be a little more efficient. Accessing a cell would be `flatarray[x+y*width]`.But you should profile first to ensure you need this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Arrays.fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5b%5d,%20int%29) method to fill single dimensional array: -

```
int[] array = new int[5];
Arrays.fill(array, -1);
```

To fill 2-dimensional array, you can apply the above method to each single dimensional array by iterating.

```
int[][] multiArr = new int[10][10];
for (int[] innerArr: multiArr) {
    Arrays.fill(innerArr, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Arrays.fill()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29)

```
public static void fill(int[][] array, int element) {
    for(int[] subarray : array) {
        Arrays.fill(subarray, element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For one dimensional array you can use

```
int[] array = new int[9000];
Arrays.fill(array, -1)
```

but for multidimensional array you will have to use a loop.

Your requirement of not using a loop sounds rather arbitrary, because in fact even in the case of a one dimensional array you are using a loop. It is just hidden away in the `fill` method. At a technical level there is no way of filling a data structure without looping over it!

You best learn to stop worrying and love the for loop.