# JavaScript style array filling in Java

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, arraylist

In JavaScript, the following:

```
var a = [];
a[20] = "hello";
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

would yield:

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"hello"]
```

Is there a list type in Java that will auto expand when setting values beyond it's current bounds? A map isn't practical because I also need to know the array dimension.

Comment: try ArrayList class, present in java.utils package

Comment: @Sarthak Mittal - ArrayList does not autofill. You cannot set an element past the end.

Comment: @jalynn2 yeah you are right, but what do you mean by, "You cannot set an element past the end"?

Comment: @SarthakMittal If there are `x` elements in the list, then you can't add another element on position `y` if `y > x`. In other words: if there are 5 elements in a list, `list.add(10, "blub");` will fail.

Comment: If the ArrayList is empty, you may only set into element 0. If it has one item, you may only set into element 0 and 1, etc. If you try to set into a greater index, you will get IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @jalynn2 yeah that's true :) , maybe we just interpret the question differently :)

Comment: _Auto expanding_ is not the same as _auto filling_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such implementation is not provided in the standard JDK, but you can use a [`GrowthList`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/GrowthList.html) (from [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)).

```
List<String> list = new GrowthList<>(); //[]
list.add(5, "test"); //[null, null, null, null, null, test]
```

Answer (score 2):

In the standard JDK there is not such a class.

Your best bet is probably to create a wrapper around an ArrayList 
and provide methods like set(int index,Object value)

Its implementation would look like this:

```
public void set(int index,Object value) {
   while (list.size() <= index) {
       list.add(null); // filling the gaps
   }   
   list.set(index,value); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29).Take a look at this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777108/how-to-autofill-an-array-in-java).

Comment: Arrays.fill functions on ordinary, static arrays, and throws an exception if the index is out of bounds. It expands nothing.